# Two different quantum mechanics books with same case depicted

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

what is the case depicted and whats special enough about it to appear on two different books?

[image]

[image]

Comment: it is a [wave packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet).

Comment: A localised wave packet? I have the first book.

Answer (score 3):

It's a wave packet to illustrate the math representation of a particle using a collection of plane waves, with a gaussian factor included to ensure the localisation of the packet, that is, it keeps the waves interfering in the correct manner and delays dispersion of the waves, which will be inevitable in any case. The wave packet cannot actually represent an electron,  for example, the dispersion rate is much too fast.

You are getting the down votes (not by myself) because the solution is literally, in your hands, just flick through the early chapters.

Comment: i dont mind the downvotes. are there any examples of natural wave packets and their mechanisms ? lets say from the picture above it looks like a coupling between two oscillators with ones amplitude phaselocked the carrier

Comment: What is the meaning of color (area under the curve) in the first image? Any comment on why it is "k" in the second image?

Comment: @user1583209 $k$ is the direction of momentum, it's in 1 D here,  also used for the propagation of a light wave. Color is just for contrast. It's schematic, not any more than that.

Comment: @ErezSabran  the illustration is just following tradition of expecting potential buyers to recognize what their teachers draw on the board. Inside the book, you should see wriggly bits in front and less wriggle at the back. In other words, more details to distinguish it from a hundred other potential sources.